# webservice callout without future

Tags: apex, batch, webservices, scheduled-apex, future

I have a trigger on the user object which calls an external web service to assign some values to every newly inserted user but now client want to insert the user's via batch(which we don't have access to) so I want to know if we can call web service without future or any way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callout in batch Apex, to do that you must specify `Database.AllowsCallouts` in the class definition as explained in this [link](http://salesforce-walker.blogspot.in/2013/09/callouts-in-batch-apexstate-in-batch.html).

For example the syntax will be:

```
global class SearchAndReplace implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, 
   Database.AllowsCallouts{
              //Business logic you want by implementing Batchable interface methods
}
```

Also, you can refer to this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19444/batch-apex-with-webservice-callout) for implementation.

Comment: The problem here is we don't have access to batch that inserts user's as it is handled by client

Comment: You can write a utility class which handles the call out and ask the client to implement the interface and invokes your utility class method to perform the action.